# How to change background color status bar in Xamarine?

Tags: xamarin

I have seen many app they have a background image that goes up to the very top of the phone.  I've been trying to achieve that on my xamarine project, but still not working.  The navigation bar is still show the blue background color ..etc

How can I change the background of the navigation bar and also the very top bar which has the time and battery and wifi? I would like to change whole background color of the app.

Answer (score -2):

**Android:**

Set the code below in `OnCreate` method of `MainActivity`:

```
    this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
```

**iOS:**

Add the values into Info.plist(right click the file to view code).

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
```

Or you could double click the file to select the Hide status bar.

[image]

Comment: The question is how to have content go beyond the safe area IOS. not how to hide the status bar. Keeping status bar info while be able to change the background color and foreground color.